# Why are my label references for subfigures not working?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

Please help me! I have this code:

````
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering textblabla1]{{\includegraphics[trim={0 0 34.5cm 0},clip, width=5cm]{mypng1.png} }}%
    \label{fig:bla1}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering textblabla2]{{\includegraphics[trim={0 0 34.5cm 0},clip, width=5cm]{mypng2.png} }}%
    \label{fig:bla2}%
\end{figure}```
````

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I just get question marks from LaTeX when I do \subref{fig:bla1} , \ref{fig:bla1} or \protect\subref{fig:bla1} ...

Comment: Please tell us which package -- `subfig`, `subcaption`, `subfigure`, something else? -- you employ to obtain the `\subfloat` macro.

Comment: This is all I have as imports: https://pastebin.com/5bbjiHXm

Comment: Put the `\label` commands at the end of the respective captions, not outside. Moreover, have a look at some tutorial how to set up subfigures, like [https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3):_Figures,_Subfigures_and_Tables](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3):_Figures,_Subfigures_and_Tables).

Answer (score 1):

I understand your document loads the `subcaption` package, which provides the command `\subfloat`. The syntax of this command is patterned after the `\subfloat` macro of the older (and possibly no longer maintained) `subfig` package.

According to pp. 36f. of the user guide of the `subfig` package, the `\label` command has to be included in either the mandatory or (if provided) the optional argument of `\subfloat`. Both possibilities are explored in the following MWE (mininum working example).

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \subfloat[textblabla1]{%
              \includegraphics[trim={0 0 34.5cm 0},clip, width=5cm]{mypng1.png}\label{fig:bla1}}
    \qquad
    \subfloat[textblabla2\label{fig:bla2}]{%
              \includegraphics[trim={0 0 34.5cm 0},clip, width=5cm]{mypng2.png}}

    \caption{Overall figure caption}\label{fig:overall}
\end{figure}

Cross-references to \cref{fig:bla1,fig:bla2}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works easily.

```
     \begin{figure}
\caption{bla bla ..}
        \begin{subfigure}{t}{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{bla bla ..}
            \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.333\textwidth,height=0.25\textwidth]{mypng1.png} 
            \label{fig:bla1}
         \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{t}{0.3\textwidth}  
\caption{bla ...}
           \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.333\textwidth,height=0.25\textwidth]{mypng2.png} 
            \label{fig:bla2}%
        \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}
```

the size is tunable